# I have installed pylint. But it doesn't display the statistics by type, raw metrics , duplication ,etc. tables. How do I get pylint display it?

Tags: python, pylint

> C:\Users\dominic.lopes\Desktop>pylint Exception.py
>   ************* Module Exception
>   Exception.py:1:0: C0103: Module name "Exception" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style (invalid-name)
>   Exception.py:11:4: C0103: Constant name "x" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style (invalid-name)
>   Exception.py:12:4: C0103: Constant name "y" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style (invalid-name)
>   Exception.py:21:44: E0602: Undefined variable 'count' (undefined-variable)

---

Your code has been rated at 3.85/10 (previous run: 6.92/10, -3.08)

This is the error traceback i get

Answer (score 9):

If you are using a more recent version of pylint (that is, >1.7), you will need to pass either `-ry` or `--reports=yes` to pylint as in `pylint <your file> --reports=yes`. The report section is now disabled by default in more recent versions so you have to activate it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue. Just run the below command:

```
pylint -ry "fileName.py"
```

Note: *Run this command at your file location.*